# How can I get form data and send it to discord webhook?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, discord

I'm building a small dashboard that will send the data to discord in the form of a webhook. I was able to retrieve the data from the form but not sure how to go about sending it to discord using node.js and discord.js. This is what I have right now. I did some research and saw something about request being the way to fetch the data but not sure how to start it.

```
form = document.getElementById("submit-form");
sucessMsg = document.getElementById("success");

function sucess(event) {
sucessMsg.style.display = "inline"
event.preventDefault()
console.log("form data:", getData())


}

function getData()
{
const formData = new FormData(form),
ret = {};

for(let [name, value] of formData.entries())
ret[name] = value;

 return ret;
 } 


form.addEventListener("submit" , sucess )
```

Comment: Peruse [these docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send). It talks about sending messages. You'll need to obtain the channel you want to send to first.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need the webhook id and token, to get these informations go to Server Settings>Integrations>Webhooks and click on the pretended webhook and copy  the webhook URL.
Paste the URL on google to see the webhook's ID and Token.

```
const id = '';
const token = '';
const webhook = new Discord.WebhookClient(id, token);
webhook.send('Your message');
```

On this example you do not need to define channelID because the channelID was defined when you created the bot.

Hope it helps you! If you need anything else just let me know.

Comment: I'm not using webhooks for this bot, i have other commands they send directly to channel with no webhook